# Regex to select a string not having a certain word followed by a certain set of words

Tags: regex

I am trying to find a regex that will return **true** if a string ends with `jaxws.managed` but does not contain `delegate`.

For example:

`abc/delegate/xyz/jaxws/managed`  should return **false**, while

`abc/def/xyz/jaxws/managed` should return **true**

I tried using the regex

```
([^(delegate)])+([a-z]*[\\/]jaxws[\\/]managed[\\/])+
```

but it fails.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Java regex,

```
^(?!.*delegate).*jaxws/managed$
```

Answer (score 1):

You should specify what regex engine you're using.

Nevertheless...

return false if it contains "delegate" anywhere:
 /delegate/; -> return false

if we don't return, and it ends in "jaxws/managed", return true:
 /jaxws\/managed$/; -> return true

if you're using Perl, I suggest applying m{} instead of // to avoid the "leaning toothpick syndrome". Refer to perlre for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Javascript, you can use this regEx:

```
 **/^((?!(delegate)).)*jaxws\/managed$/**
```